# Get attribute label/option by custom attribute code magento

Tags: php, magento, attributes, label

How can I get my custom created product attribute label/option using attribute code .

My Attribute Code is for example 'amazon_pdt_url' .

I have tried

```
$label = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('amazon_pdt_url')->getFrontend()->getLabel($product);
```

Which returned

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getResource() on null in ....

Also tried

```
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute(‘amazon_pdt_url’)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getFrontend() on boolean in

Please help to achieve this on my phtml file.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you get `$product`? Is it instance of `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` or `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor`?

Comment: Please share more info, what type the attribute it is ? is it enabled to show on frontend ? on which page are you trying to fetch the attribute data ? etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on my list.phtml

```
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();
$storeId = $store->getStoreId();
$attributeModel = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product','amazon_pdt_url');
echo $attributeModel->getStoreLabel($storeId);die;
```

If this is not what you want then  may be i misunderstood your question.